# limits on discrete and continous values

Tags: limits

Given that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) = c \in \mathbb{R}$, it follows that also $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(n) = c$ is true $(n \in \mathbb{N})$. It seems pretty straight forward, as the set of natural numbers is a subset of real numbers, but is this the sole (and sufficient) reason why? Can we make any general statements about the other direction (if we reverse the implication)? I was thinking about formulating this with sequences and subsequences, but this won't get me anywhere further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to be careful, because $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin{n \pi} = 0$. The reason this phenomenon exists is because, for the other direction, you know apriori no matter which way you take you will get to your destination, but in the other case (the provided example) we don't know.

For example, $\overline{z}$ is discontinuous at the origin in $\mathbb{C}$, because taking two different paths to the origin yield two different limits.

Comment: lim_(x->infinity) sin(x pi) = -1 to 1; so it doesn't have a limit... we have implication here, so it doesn't matter if lim_(n->infinity) sin (n pi) = 0

Comment: Right! Thats what I was getting at.